# Does the Taylor series of $\ln(x)$ about $1$ allow domain extension?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, taylor-expansion, divergent-series

Many series representations allow for domain extension.  That is, the series for $\sin(x)$ allows you to find the value of $\sin(i)$ or similar.  However, when I take the series for $\ln(x)$, it doesn't seem to actually map to the complex domain, and I am not sure why.

The series I have is:
$$ \ln(x) = \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1}\frac{1}{n}(x - 1)^n $$
If I expand it out to four terms, I get:
$$ \ln(x) = (x - 1) - \frac{(x - 1)^2}{2} + \frac{(x - 1)^3}{3} + \frac{(x - 1)^4}{4} $$
Now, I realize that, with only four terms, it is not going to be incredibly accurate, but nonetheless it should be in the ballpark.  Additionally, this should converge if $0 < x < 2$.  However, I'm not for certain whether or not the complex $i$ would converge, nor actually how to tell on complex numbers.  So that could be the problem, but then I don't know how to figure out which complex values this converges for.

If I substitute $i$ in I get $\frac{2}{3} + \frac{8}{3}i$, while the actual value is $\frac{i \pi}{2}$.  In fact, if I extend it to a full ten terms of the expansion, I get $-3.45 + 4.37i$ (rounded for simplicity), which is even further away.

Anyway, I'm sure that my lack of knowledge of complex analysis is biting me, but I thought I'd see if there was a simple answer, and if there was a way to figure the complex radius of convergence of the Taylor series for $\ln(x)$ about $1$.

Comment: **Hint**: For which $x$ your Taylor expansion is valid? Compare with the Taylor expansion of $\sin$.

Comment: You can evaluate that series at all the complex numbers with $|x-1|<1$. But $i$ is too far from $1$. $|i-1|=\sqrt{2}>1$.

Comment: Aha!  Thank you for that.  I was thinking that since 0 < x < 2, then as long as |i - 1| < 2 that it would work. However, your answer makes perfect sense.  You should write that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taylor series of holomorphic functions converge up to the nearest singularity. As exists an holomorphic extension of $\sin:\Bbb R \longrightarrow\Bbb R$ the Taylor series of $\sin$ converges in $\Bbb C$. But in the case of the logarithm...